# How to initialize the size of the an array and a pointer to the array in assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

I am quite new to this and I am working on an assignment in basicly translate c to armv7. The following code are the intializations

```
int array[] = {5, 6, 7, 8};
size_t n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
int *ptr;
ptr = &array[0];
```

The following are for the pointers in assembly:

```
array: .word 5, 6, 7, 8
       LDR R0, =array //R0 is the address where the array starts
       MOV R1, #0 // for teh iteration variable i
       LDR R1, [Ro, R1] //
```

Did I do everything correctly for now? And I have no idea how to cope with the sizeof thing. And I am looking forward for your help!

Comment: ..............           ...........

Answer (score 0):

To the assembler and assembly code, a pointer is a pointer is a pointer. It's just a memory address. It's up to you to write the assembly code that is appropriate for the kind of object that is pointed to. Likewise, the assembly code knows nothing about the size of your array. It's up to you to write code that stays within the bounds of the array. Usually this will mean that you define some constant that is the size of the array, and then use that constant as necessary to make your code work. There's no magic here.